# replace a character in mysql with a random character from a list

Tags: mysql, sql

i would like to perform Mysql search & replace with random characters, taken from a list. I cannot use regex, since my version is way prior to 8.
instead of the below,

i would like to change for instance the letter u with one out of (a,e,i,f,k) randomly.

```
UPDATE products 
SET 
    productDescription = REPLACE(productDescription,
        'abuot',
        'about');
```

Is there a mysql command for this task?
Actually my goal is to get in the lastnames column, new names that are not exactly like the real ones, so one could work on "anonymous" data.

I would like to replace all rows in a certain column. Say in table products, in column description, we have data like:

```
abcud
ieruie
kjuklkllu
uiervfd
```

With the replace function, we would not want to create something like: replace e with i,
but replace e with one of (a,e,i,f,k)

example desired output:

```
abced
ierfie
kjiklkllk
aiervfd
```

like i said, we plan to use this into last names, we plan to replace many characters with random ones from a list, in an effort to create anonymous data in the column that contains last names.

On a next step, i would like to do the same, in order to make anonymous telephone numbers.

example

```
726456273
827364878
347823472
```

replace 3 with one of 0-9,

output:

```
726456279
827664878
547821472
```

Comment: i would like the replacement in all rows, and not the same replacement everywhere. Since i need to make lastnames anonymous, if i replace say i with o in the column, perhaps it is obvious that John Smoth, has come from John Smith.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  REPLACE('product abuot Description',
SUBSTRING('product abuot Description', CHARINDEX('abuot', 'product abuot Description') ,5) , 'about')

Comment: you can use.  SELECT CASE CHARINDEX('u', 'product', 1)
     WHEN 0 THEN 'product' 
     ELSE  REPLACE ('product', 'u', 'i')
END  -- change the i with the result of your random query

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION smart_replace ( argument TEXT, 
                                search_for CHAR(1),
                                replace_with TEXT )
RETURNS TEXT
NO SQL
BEGIN
SET argument = REPLACE(argument, search_for, CHAR(0));
REPEAT
    SET argument = CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(argument, CHAR(0), 1),
                           SUBSTRING(replace_with FROM CEIL(RAND() * LENGTH(replace_with)) FOR 1),
                           SUBSTRING(argument FROM 2 + LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(argument, CHAR(0), 1))));
UNTIL NOT LOCATE(CHAR(0), argument) END REPEAT;
RETURN argument;
END
```

---

> replace `e` with one of `(a,e,i,f,k)`

```
SELECT smart_replace(table.column, 'e', 'aeifk')
```

> replace `3` with one of `0-9`

```
SELECT smart_replace(table.phone, 'e', '0123456789')
```

Comment: i run the above in mysql, and i got an error 1109, that the table does not exist... When it does exist. am i missing something?

Comment: @voteba Table? What table? The function does not use any table, so your error is out of the function.

Comment: is the call of the function for sure this? SELECT smart_replace(table.phone, '8', '0123456789'); Also my columns i need to change have as datatype VARCHAR(255). SELECT smart_replace('table.phone8', '8', '0123456789');  works, it changes the text given as parameter. But how i could give as an argument for each row, the column;s value?